# How can I attach an image to these rectangles in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a functioning game like frogger, but it is only rectangles and squares currently. I was wondering if there was a way to simply "skin" the rectangles with an image instead of an RGB color.

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
class Frog(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w):
        super(Frog, self).__init__(x, y, w, w)
        self.x0 = x
        self.y0 = y
        self.color = (34, 177, 76)
        self.attached = None

    def reset(self):
        self.x = self.x0
        self.y = self.y0
        self.attach(None)

    def move(self, xdir, ydir):
        self.x += xdir * g_vars['grid']
        self.y += ydir * g_vars['grid']

    def attach(self, obstacle): 
        self.attached = obstacle

    def update(self):
        if self.attached is not None:
            self.x += self.attached.speed

        if self.x + self.w > g_vars['width']:
            self.x = g_vars['width'] - self.w

        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 0
        if self.y + self.h > g_vars['width']:
            self.y = g_vars['width'] - self.w
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0

    def draw(self):
        rect = Rect( [self.x, self.y], [self.w, self.h] )
        pygame.draw.rect( g_vars['window'], self.color, rect )
```

Comment: instead of drawing rectangle you can load image (and you have `Surface`) which you can display `blit(image, image_rect)`

Answer (score 0):

Forget rectangle. You don't "skin" rectange. You load image and draw it (blit it) directly on screen.

```
class Frog:

    def __init__(self, x, y, filename):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        #self.rect.w = w # no need it - rect will use image's width
        #self.rect.h = h # no need it - rect will use image's height

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

if you use [pygame.sprite.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) then you can even skip `def draw()` because it already have it

```
class Frog(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, filename):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        #self.rect.w = w # no need it - rect will use image's width
        #self.rect.h = h # no need it - rect will use image's height

    #def draw(self, screen):
    #    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    # Sprite already has this method
```

Now you use `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` instead of `self.x`, `self.y` because some other functions use `self.rect` to check collision ([pygame.sprite.collide_rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect)) or draw all sprites in group ([pygame.sprite.Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)).

With `self.rect` you can also assign  `x, y` to center of image

```
    self.rect.centerx = x
    self.rect.centery = y
```

and it will calculate `self.rect.x` , `self.rect.y`

Doc: [pygame.image.load()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load), [pygame.sprite.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), [pygame.sprite.collide_rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect), [pygame.sprite.Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me with this! I'll post how it comes out.